# Why is there sound aboard Concorde after it goes supersonic?

Tags: reference-frames, acoustics, aircraft, shock-waves

I recently saw a video from a passenger of Concorde after it goes supersonic. Inside the aircraft, there is still a loud roar similar to what we hear in aircraft today.

However, since the aircraft is supersonic, shouldn't the noise be left behind? Why is the roar present? I was expecting the aircraft to be nearly silent due to being supersonic, and it appears that is far from the reality.

Comment: The noise from the engines couples through the airframe to the cabin, all of which are moving in the same frame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Air flowing over the wings, even in supersonic conditions, rattles and shakes and whistles against the skin of the plane, which means those noises come through the walls of the plane and are audible inside it.

The engines produce a mighty roar and since they are bolted to the wings which are bolted to the body of the plane, they too will be audible inside it.

The air conditioning fans inside the plane that move air through the overhead ball vents will also be audible.

Answer (score 3):

The supersonic aircraft is moving with supersonic velocity relative to the air fluid outside through which it is travelling. But, there is NO relative velocity between the aircraft and the air fluid inside the aircraft. So sound can propagate as normal inside the aircraft.